# PHP Echo Styling output

Tags: php, styles

```
<?php
if (in_array($key,$following)){
        echo ' <form id="follow" action= "action.php" method="GET" data-theme="a">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="$key"/>
        <input type="submit" name="do" value="follow" data-theme="a"/>
</form>';

?>
```

I am trying to style this echo section.  I have it outputting to another PHP file that is framed in HTML div tags.  How would I go about this?  I have everything else on the page styled correctly except for this output.

Edit** I edited the code, that's a form.  But anyway, I have another php file that is referencing this php code and on the 2nd php file it is wrapped in html and the div tag on that page shows the echo from this page but I can't get the css to work on that other file. And I have tried #follow. no luck.

Comment: So what do you mean by "styling"?

Comment: What do you mean you "have it outputting to another PHP file that is framed in HTML div tags"? In which file is the above code?

Either way, you can get to it easily in your CSS using `#follow` for the div.

Comment: I have not seen a DIV tag having `action` and `method="GET"` before. am I missing something?

Comment: @tcoder: nope, you're not missing something. that is indeed a div trying very hard to pretend to be a form.

Comment: from the "data-theme" I'm assuming you are using jquery mobile right?

Comment: BTW you are trying to let PHP parse variables in a single quoted string, which doesn't work

Comment: yes i am using jquery mobile. and I edited the code and added some more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create your own function:

```
function myecho($text){
    echo "<div class='your_css_class'>".$text."</div>";
}
```

And when you want to echo something just write `myecho("my message");`

Comment: I don't see what a function would do in this case, than again I don't get OP's question.

Comment: I don't know for sure but I think he wants to style his echo-ed text.Maybe in a styled div

Comment: thats correct boyd, but this php code is referenced on another file, where i have all the HTML. the echo-ed text gets on to that page but the styling from that other page doesn't work.

Comment: It seems you have a path problem.Check your paths for the .css files